# При получение письма через mailkit в поле from непонятный набор символов

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, imap, mailkit

В outlook отправляю любое письмо контакту в адресной книге.
потом в своем почтовом клиенте пытаюсь получить поле from

```
var from = message.From.Mailboxes.FirstOrDefault()?.Address;
```

И в нем лежит следующая строка:

```
IMCEAEX-_O=FIRST+20ORGANIZATION_OU=EXCHANGE+20ADMINISTRATIVE+20GROUP+28FYDIBOHF23SPDLT+29_CN=RECIPIENTS_CN=00037FFE69354E9A@sct-15-20-4755-11-msonline-outlook-80ceb.templateTenant
```

Как получить именно почтовый ящик?? а не набор символов?

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть все, что находится в `Mailboxes`, и посмотрите их тип. Могу предположить, что брать первый в некоторых случаях некорректно, но это так, чисто догадка.

Comment: К сожалению все там просмотрел( и нигде нет корректного почтового ящика. 
В gmail такой проблемы не было, мб какая то особенность реализации imap именно outlook